# Filtering Null values in Select

Tags: linq

I have IQueryable list of objects of type T which I want to transform into objects of type K

```
List<K> tranformedList = originalList.Select(x => transform(x)).ToList();
```

the transform function returns null if it cannot tranform the objects.If I want to filter out null elements can I call

```
List<K> tranformedList = originalList.Select(x => transform(x))
                                     .Where(y => y != default(K))
                                     .ToList();
```

or is there any other way of filtering out null elements when calling Select in LINQ ?

Comment: Will you accept solutions for IEnumerable? IQueryable is potentially a little more complicated, but perhaps you only need IEnumerable support.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Can't you just do something like this:

```
List<K> tranformedList = originalList.Select(x => tranform(x))
                                 .Where(y => y != null) //Check for nulls
                                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 84):

What about

```
    List<K> tranformedList = originalList
                             .Select(transform)
                             .OfType<K>()
                             .ToList()
```

Takes care of unboxing an getting rid of nulls at the same time (especially when K is a struct)

David B I dont believe you that your code `.Where(y => y != null)` works when K is an int! There is NO WAY you will get that code to compile if K is an int!

Comment: Excellent answer, this is the way to do it.

Comment: I like this answer. Could you do `.OfType<object>` as a more generic approach, as null will never be of type object, but any other object will? Or will this cause boxing/unboxing (which you mention) which is computationally expensive?

Comment: What is the performance difference with ".Select([...]).Where(y => y != null)"? I could imagine the latter iterates twice a collection, what does ".Select([...]).OfType<K>()" do?

Comment: Great answer - results in a non-nullable type list

Answer (score 1):

```
List<K> tranformedList = originalList.Select(x => transform(x))
                                     .Where(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y))
                                     .ToList();
```

After your Select linq query, filter null values with **!string.IsNullOrEmpty("string")** or **string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("string")** in your Where query.

Comment: Just take care when using asn Iqueryable, some ODBC couuld not recognize the isNullOrEmpty and other exclusive C# class methods

Answer (score 0):

Use Where Instead of Select (Linq).

Where returns the list without null values directly

List tranformedList = originalList.Where(x => x != null).ToList();

Comment: `Where<T>()` will return `IEnumerable<T>`, which will be some subset of the original set.  `Select<T, TResult>()` will return `IEnumerable<TResult>`, some set of new objects selected, based on the old set of objects and the function provided (which accepts an item of type T).  Whatever the return type of the `Func` passed to `Select()` will determine what type of object you get back.  Moreover, even if T == TResult, the result set may not be the same items, or even a subset of the original items.  So Select and Where are not equivalent at all really, and Where isn't a good choice here.

Answer (score -1):

You could try a for loop and add the non nulls to the new transformed list.

```
foreach (var original in originalList)
{
    K transformed = tranform(orignal);
    if (transformed != null)
    {
        tranformedList.Add(transformed);
    }
}
```

or you could try

```
        List<K> tranformedList = (from t in
                                      (from o in originalList
                                       select tranform(o))
                                  where t != null
                                  select t).ToList();
```

I think Nathan's works as well but is less verbose