# Whats wrong with this LINQ query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

```
var item1 = (from a in db.Item
                         where
                         (a.ItemNo == Item.ItemNo ||  Item.ItemNo==null ) &&
                         (a.StatusId == Item.StatusId || Item.StatusId == 0) &&
                           (a.LocationId == Item.LocationId || Item.LocationId == 0)
                         select a).ToList();

            return View(item1);
```

I  am  getting exception

```
[ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = isnull ]
```

I have also  tried this  code

```
 var item1 = (from a in db.Item
                         where
                         (a.ItemNo == Item.ItemNo ||  Item.ItemNo=="") &&
                         (a.StatusId == Item.StatusId || Item.StatusId == 0) &&
                           (a.LocationId == Item.LocationId || Item.LocationId == 0)
                         select a).ToList();

            return View(item1);
```

But  Not  working getting Error

```
[String truncation: max=0, len=2, value='10'. ]
```

Comment: what's `Item` in (for example) a.ItemNo == `Item`.ItemNo

Comment: Item is  object  of table  or class

Comment: i  am  trying  but  getting  conversion  error  i  understood  ur  logic  Means If  String  is  empty  Pass  default  value  else Pass value..  but  getting  conversion error IS  "There is  no implicit conversion between string and bool"

Comment: hey just one change in edited answer you need to put a.ItemNo==a.ItemNo rather than a.ItemNo only , you can check in my answer...

Comment: [[ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = isnull ]]    getting  this  error  again  while  using  urs  statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try writing it as a Lamdba expression, see if it is the same issue?

```
var item1 = db.Item.Where(a => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Item.ItemNo) || a.ItemNo == Item.ItemNo) &&
                               (Item.StatusId == 0 || a.StatusId == Item.StatusId) &&
                               (Item.LocationId == 0 || a.LocationId == Item.LocationId)).FirstOrDefault();

return View(item1);
```

**Update**

Appears EF doesn't support `String.IsNullOrEmpty` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368946/linq-syntax-where-string-value-is-not-null-or-empty). You can re-write your query like:

```
var item1 = db.Item.Where(a => ((Item.ItemNo == null || Item.ItemNo == String.Empty) || a.ItemNo == Item.ItemNo) &&
                               (Item.StatusId == 0 || a.StatusId == Item.StatusId) &&
                               (Item.LocationId == 0 || a.LocationId == Item.LocationId))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you are still having trouble checking for null, then you could break the query up e.g.

```
var query = db.Item.Where(a => (Item.StatusId == 0 || a.StatusId == Item.StatusId) &&
                               (Item.LocationId == 0 || a.LocationId == Item.LocationId));

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Item.ItemNo))
{
    query = query.Where(a => a.ItemNo == Item.ItemNo);
}

var item1 = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: i  am  getting  same  error     [ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = isnull ]

Comment: @KapsHasija EF doesn't support `String.IsNullOrEmpty` which is why you are seeing that particular exception. See my updated post.

Comment: @KapsHasija what type is `ItemNo`?

Comment: Why don't you test each individual condition separately to see which one is failing (may not necessarily be the `ItemNo` one).

Comment: i  have  tested  to  comment  my  itemno.  code  ,  problam  only occurred  with  Itemno.  Thanks  waiting  for  reply  badly

Comment: @KapsHasija I take it if you remove the check for `null` completely it works ok? There are no known issues I can think of with checking for null with EF.

Comment: hi  james  i  found  main  error  actually  thing  is  that  when  i  used  my  query  with  web grid  or  normal  lay out  ..it  works well  but  when  i  used  jquery  grid  it  not  works..  have  you  any  idea

Comment: @KapsHasija Sorry never used jQuery Grid before, you might be better either re-posting a new question focusing it towards jQuery grid users or post it on their forums.

Comment: @KapsHasija Check the update to my answer. It might solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Try soemthing like this

```
 string.IsNullOrEmpty(Item.ItemNo) ? a.ItemNo==a.ItemNo
                  : a.ItemNo == Item.ItemNo;
```

code for you is

```
var item1 = (from a in db.Item 
                    where
                    ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(Item.ItemNo) ? a.ItemNo==a.ItemNo
                  : a.ItemNo == Item.ItemNo; ) &&
                     ..more
```

**Note**  if the value of `Item.ItemNo` is null or empty than you should do `a.ItemNo==a.ItemNo` sot hat it satisfy your condition...

---

Make sure that Your itmeno field is nullable as like below

```
int? ItemNo { get; set; }
```

and tryout soemthing like this

```
Item.ItemNo == null ? a.ItemNo : a.ItemNo == Item.ItemNo
```

so it will ve

```
var item1 = (from a in db.Item 
                    where
                    ( Item.ItemNo == null ? a.ItemNo : a.ItemNo == Item.ItemNo ) &&
                     ..more
```

Comment: My  ItemNo Column is String Type so  What  i  have  to  do?

Comment: i  am  getting  same  error     [ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = isnull ]