# How can I check if a value exists in a list using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code that gives me a list of id and names from the new ASP.NET MVC5 Identity:

```
        var identityStore = new IdentityStore();
        var users =
          (
              from user in identityStore.DbContext.Set<User>()
              select new
              {
                  id = user.Id,
                  name = user.UserName
              }
          );
```

How could I modify this so that it allows me to check if a UserName exists?

Here's the user class:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public User();
    public User(string userName);

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserLogin> Logins { get; set; }
    public virtual UserManagement Management { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Exists where? Can you please add some explanations its a little vague.

Comment: are you looking for something along `var isUserExist = identityStore.DbContext.Set<User>().Any(user => user.UserName == "Samantha")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(identityStore.DbContext.Set<User>().Any(u => UserName == "yourUserName"))
{
    // user exists
}
else
{
    // user does not exist
}
```

Does it fit for your requirements? Your question is bit unclear.

Comment: Yes I think it's perfect. I will try it now.

Comment: a small correction , it should be Any(u => u.UserName == "yourUserName")

Answer (score 1):

You can query the username with a where statement if this is what you want, e.g.

```
var users = from user in identityStore.DbContext.Set<User>()
            where user.UserName != null && !user.UserName.Equals(string.Empty)
            select ...
```

anyways, it is a possible duplicate of this answer [LINQ syntax where string value is not null or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368946/linq-syntax-where-string-value-is-not-null-or-empty)

string.IsNullOrEmpty does work only in some cases, so be careful!

Or if you just look for a specific user name, simply query for it

```
var users = from user in identityStore.DbContext.Set<User>()
            where user.UserName.Equals("whatever")
            select ...
```