# C# LINQ - Does Select filter nulls when used with a method group?

Tags: c#, linq, resharper, method-group

Today I wrote some code that takes a list of class A instances and creates a list of class B instances using a static factory method:

```
public abstract class B
{
    public static B CreateB(A a)
    {
        // return a new B instance or null if a B instance can't be created
    }
}
```

I needed to filter out the nulls so I used LINQ to do both tasks:

```
var bList = aList.Select(a => B.CreateB(a)).Where(b => b != null).ToList();
```

Code runs like expected, but I noticed Resharper was suggesting, on the call to CreateB, I should "Convert to method group". I wondered what that means and found some interesting answers on this site. For example:
[What is a method group in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c) and a comment by Asad to stitty's answer here [Filtering Null values in Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401935/filtering-null-values-in-select) (.Select(x => transform(x)) can be .Select(transform))

So I changed my code to:

```
var bList = aList.Select(B.CreateB).Where(b => b != null).ToList();
```

This too works as expected, but now I get to my question. Resharper now tells me  the Where lambda expression can be removed because b != null "is always true".

I played around and Resharper is correct, but why? Why is there a difference in the returned collection of the Select() when I use a method group? Why does the Select() seem to filter out the nulls out of the collection when I use a method group?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - how does the static method CreateB() 'return a new B instance'? Will it create an inherited class instance? I know it has nothing to do with your question, it's just that I have never seen such a design before (and I'm not an expert, either).

Comment: Are you sure? I just reconstructed your example and I don't get anything about removing the `Where` clause.

Comment: @shay__ B is an abstract class and CreateB() returns an instance of an inherited class (or null).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Well, Resharper doesn't say "Remove the Were clause", it says the "Expression is always true" about the b != null check.

Comment: I understand. But I don't get that either.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Me too, that's why I posted this question.

Comment: No I mean, I don't get the ReSharper hint, not the semantics :) Is `A` a reference type? I think we're missing something in your type declaration. Perhaps post your actual types?

Comment: Is "a" null too, if an instance of B cannot be created?

Comment: Yes, A is some custom object I have. B is abstract as I mentioned in an earlier comment, maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: @mDC The aList doesn't contain any nulls. I just can't map all instances of A to a B instance so the CreateB() method returns null in this case.

Comment: @mDC What contents of bList do you get if you replace `CreateB` with `return null;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `aList.Select(a => B.CreateB(a)).Where(b => b != null).ToList();` and `aList.Select(B.CreateB).Where(b => b != null).ToList();` use the same overload of `Select` method.

I tested it with LinqPad and got the following output:

[image: LinqPad]

So `Select` doesn't filter anything. What version of Resharper and VisualStudio are you using?

Latest ReSharper on VS2013 doesn't tell anything:

[image: Latest ReSharper on VS2013]

Comment: Thanks for testing. I'm using VisualStudio 2012 with Resharper 9.0 update 1.

Comment: Turns out this is a bug in ReSharper. I debugged the Where clause by changing it to: .Where(item => { return item != null; }) and while Resharper  says "Expression is always true" it is actually false.

Comment: Try upgrading to ReSharper 9.1.1 or the 9.2 EAP. If it's still reported as an error, it's a bug, and should be reported to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com